# Como criar uma variável de ambiente windows

Tags: batch, variáveis-de-ambiente

Preciso criar uma variável de ambiente no windows, através de um batch.

Posso criar uma variável local com o

```
set variavel=valor
```

Mas preciso acessar esse valor através de outros batch.
como faço para criar uma variável do windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar uma variável de ambiente é necessário ter privilegios de administrador, com isso basta usar o comanado [setx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.11).aspx)

Exemplo:

```
setx NOME valor
```

Comment: E se eu quiser deletar essa variável futuramente, qual comando uso?

Comment: Obrigado @rray :)

Comment: @Laércio Lopes REG delete HKCU\Environment /F /V **_NOME_** remove a variável.. mais detales nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207417/como-eu-posso-continuar-um-bat-em-um-novo-perfil-depois-de-reiniciar/347428#347428)